# Xcode 9 - Add an App Store icon

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode9-beta, xcode9

i saw this new requirement in itunes connect (next to the `App Store Icon`):

[image]

As for now (Xcode 8.3.x) I have AppIcon assets next to the `App Icon Source`

Is this requirement means i need to change any thing? or only that from Xcode 9.x.x the `App Icon Source` and the `App store Icons` are coupled and there is no option to change the `App Store Icon` in iTunes connect?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you're using Xcode 9 or later, you should use your *Assets catalog* (See image below) to provide an *App Store Icon* for your app like below and **there is no other way**. This way it would be easy to prep. for App Store release. You can mostly use Xcode to configure things, instead of going to iTunes/App Store Connect.

**If you are using Xcode 8.3.3 or earlier, you must use iTunes Connect to upload your App Store icon**

As of now *(September 2017)* you cannot push apps built using Xcode 9 since it is still in beta. If you want you can wait for another day or two until Xcode 9 GM build gets released. Your build will fail in the upload process if you are using Xcode 9 without adding the App Store icon resource.

For more info [read this.](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/dev8b5cb82e2)

[image: Assets Catalog - App Store icon]

Comment: So i must add `App Sore iOS` new resource? which necessarily didn't existed before? If i won't add it, will upload to up store will fail?

Comment: Yes. But as of now you cannot push apps build from Xcode 9 since it is still in beta. If you want you can wait for another day or two until Xcode 9 GM build gets released. Your build will fail in the upload process if you are using Xcode 9 without adding the App Store icon resource.

Comment: If i'll use an image for `App Store iOS` which is not in the right size (1024x1024), but smaller with the right proportions (e.g. 255x255) - Will my upload to store fail/warn/pass?

Comment: If will fail apparently. iTunes checks for the dimensions of image while uploading. You could just hire a designer just to make the icon 1024x1024.

Comment: I tried with 1024 x 1024 icon created using photoshop and illustrator but still getting the same error in xcode 9. Also app icon is not visible in simulator and iphone.

Comment: @anuragtk Did you add the icon in Asset catalog?? In App Store icon? Delete the existing App Store icon from catalog and re-add them back.

Comment: @Badhan Ganesh yes i did

Comment: If you can't visualize the missing Appstore icon in your xcassets you can also add it from the Content.json when you right clic on the AppIcon "Show in finder".

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Xcode 10 or earlier in MAC

Same icon use in appstoreconnect and another one xcode 
General->App icon and launch image->app icon source->[add image No transparent nor contain an alpha channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STL44.png)