# How to add an app icon to a react-native project without using any npm packages or 3rd party libraries? Is it even possible to do so?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to add an app icon to a react-native application and am not able to do so also could hardly find anything about this in the documentation or any other sources which I am able to implement successfully.
  Got this one working by using react-native-icon Package but is there Something like a single command to get icons configured into the respective folders when they are created using react-native eject command.

Comment: Sounds like you're using CRNA or expo?

Comment: i am just trying to run on emulator

Answer (score 1):

The app icons are controlled from the native side of the project. 
You can set them up from Xcode or Android Studio fairly easily.

Perhaps take a look at [Xcode 9 - Add an App Store icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138790/xcode-9-add-an-app-store-icon) and [Set icon for Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350624/set-icon-for-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

use [android asset studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(255%2C%20255%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

drag and drop your icon and change filters if you like and then download it.
Unzip it and then replace your res icon folder with this one

indepth tut [tutorial](https://medium.com/better-programming/react-native-add-app-icons-and-launch-screens-onto-ios-and-android-apps-3bfbc20b7d4c)